# sendto domain instead of an IP

Tags: c, networking, ip, sendto

I have two machines on two different networks. The only thing I know is their http addresses. One of the machines is listening on port UDP port 9500 and another needs to send messages to this port. Currently on my test platform I'm using hardcoded IP address and a [sendto](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html) command. In a real life situation the system each network node will have a domain name assigned to it. Is it possible to use a [sendto](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html) function to send UDP to a specific domain name?

Comment: No. You will have to use the DNS API to map the domain name to an IP address. Examples abound.

Comment: See `getaddrinfo` for name lookups.